# Trouble with creating new application on Django

Tags: python, django

I'm very new to programming and Django. I started following the Tango with Django tutorial and I'm at the part where I have to create a new app called "rango" by typing "rango" in the "settings.py" under the "INSTALLED_APPS" tuple. I follow the instructions and try to the run the server on the command prompt. I get the follow error

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\tango_with_django_project> python manage.py startapp rango
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 118, in  create
cls = getattr(mod, cls_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'staticfilesrango'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create
import_module(entry)
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfilesrango'
```

I've already tried this on visual studios and pycharm, tried it on python3.5 and 3.4, uninstalled and reinstalled python, and redid the pip install and django. Please help!

Comment: Post the exact INSTALLED_APPS setting you made. I bet you missed a comma between the apps.

Comment: sorry for the late response. Yes, i missed a comma. thank you for your help